# how to change tablename in sequelize for nodejs api

Tags: api

i create sequelize table like order-detail in small letter but sequelize took this name as orderDetail in all api pages.... but in database it insert like orderdetail ...it works in localhost fine but in live server shows there is no table like orderDetail ... so how to overcome this issue

this is my migration file
`module.exports = { async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) { await queryInterface.createTable('orderDetails', { }}}`

this is my model

```
 class orderDetails extends Model {
 
static associate(models) {
  // define association here
 models.order.hasMany(models.orderDetails);
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when we use relational database we must use migrate database and seeders you must create new seeders or new migrate file for your change in your database and in migrate you must use this model for create
your_field

and in your model in your app you can use :
yourField

Comment: thank you for your response....... in my live server i tried migration then my problem solved ... thank you